# write "message of the day" by images used by vscode remote development

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I am using remote development extension in vscode with a Docker image and I would like that when I start it in the console I want to see the message of the day "motd".

The Dockerfile in `.devcontaier` has this at the end:

```
COPY motd /etc/
... # change the default user and WORKDIR
CMD cat /etc/motd && /bin/bash
```

If I run manually this image I see the message but when vscode uses it I don't see it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is

```
RUN echo "cat /etc/motd" >> $HOME/.bashrc
CMD /bin/bash
```